# Phalcon redirection and forwarding

Tags: phalcon

Do I understand correctly that after doing `$this->dispatcher->forward()` or `$this->response->redirect()` I need to manually ensure that the rest of the code does't get executed? Like below, or am I missing something?

```
public function signinAction()
{
    if ($this->isUserAuthenticated())
    {
        $this->response->redirect('/profile');
        return;
    }

    // Stuff if he isn't authenticated…
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After almost a year of working on a hardcore project that uses Phalcon beyond its capacity, I wanted to clarify a few things and answer my own question. To understand how to properly do redirects and forwards you need to understand a little about how the [Dispatcher::dispatch](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Dispatcher.html) method works.

Take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L568), though it's all C mumbo-jumbo to most of us, its really well written and documented. In the nutshell this is what it does:

1. The dispatcher [enters](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L619) the while loop until the `_finished` property becomes `true` or it [discovers](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L634) a recursion.
2. Inside the loop, it immediately [sets](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L644) that property to `true`, so when it starts the next iteration it will automatically [break](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L626).
3. It then gets the controller / action information, which are originally supplied by the router in the application, and does various checks. Before and after that it also completes a lot of event-related business.
4. Finally it [calls](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L939) the action method in the controller and [updates](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L964) the `_returnedValue` property with (guess what!) the returned value.
5. If during the action call you call `Dispatcher::forward` method, it will [update](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L1076) the `_finished` property back to `false`, which will allow the while loop to continue from the step 2 of this list.

So, after you do redirect or forward, you need to ensure that you code doesn't get executed **only** if that is part of the expected logic. In other words you don't have to return the result of `return $this->response->redirect` or `return $this->dispatcher->forward`.

Doing the last might seem convenient, but not very correct and might lead to problems. In 99.9% cases your controller should not return anything. The exception would be when you actually know what you are doing and want to [change](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/9ce2bb076d6134794b3224e214a578d3a7ee0bf4/ext/mvc/application.c#L504) the behaviour of the rendering process in your application by returning the response object. On top of that your IDE might complain about inconsistent return statements.

To finalise, the correct way to redirect from within the controller:

```
// Calling redirect only sets the 30X response status. You also should
// disable the view to prevent the unnecessary rendering.

$this->response->redirect('/profile');
$this->view->disable();

// If you are in the middle of something, you probably don't want 
// the rest of the code running.

return;
```

And to forward:

```
$this->dispatcher->forward(['action' => 'profile']);

// Again, exit if you don't need the rest of the logic.

return;
```

Comment: wouldn't a simple `die()` be enough after `response->redirect()`? (I mean instead of disabling the view and returning)

Comment: In most cases yes, in some cases no, e.g., when there's some logic to run after action that is outside it and most frameworks, including Phalcon, do have that logic. In Phalcon case, from [here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/8aba8584d54237af9f2c0e5eba3dcc8a950cd225/ext/dispatcher.c#L964) on you can see what happens after the last action, though in most cases that doesn't play any role if you `die` on it. `die` is a hacky way to finish the request, there are a few opinions around why using it is a bad practice, especially when using a it inside a framework that handles that request.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use it like this:

```
return $this->response->redirect('/profile');
```

or

```
return $this->dispatcher->forward(array(
    'action' => 'profile'
))
```

Comment: How do you get content from forwarded controller/action without using echo?

Answer (score 2):

Use send() like this

```
public function signinAction()
{
    if ($this->isUserAuthenticated())
    {
        return $this->response->redirect('profile')->send();
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me fix it. I was only using response->redirect (with view->disable() beforehand), but still my actions (that should have been protected by a login) got executed (even though the login-page was shown), adding the missing "send()" got it working.

Comment: Thanks! I had separated function to redirect, so `return` doesn't work. Your solution helped me